# "Have you ever seen anyone walk (walking) the streets like that?"

Tags: sentence-construction, progressive-aspect, complementation

> Have you ever seen anyone **walk** the streets like that?
>
> Have you ever seen anyone **walking** the streets like that?

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same?

> I saw him **kiss** her the other day.
>
> I saw him **kissing** her the other day.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same?

And I'm sorry, if the latter two sentences come off immature .-.
I couldn't come up with better sentences.

Answer (score 1):

It's registering a single event vs witnessing continuous action.

> Have you ever seen anyone walk the streets like that?

In other words, have you ever caught a glimpse of someone (one person, or maybe two, or a hundred, on a hundred separate occasions) walk the streets in that fashion?

> Have you ever seen anyone walking the streets like that?

Have you witnessed someone, etc, and continued watching them as they walked?

> I saw him kiss her the other day.

This means you definitely remember at least one kiss.

> I saw him kissing her the other day.

You saw them in the act of kissing.